# Asp.net - implementing Help window

Tags: asp.net

I am working in ASP.Net Web Application. In my application , i have model dialogs opened. After opening model dialog , if i press F1 using keyboard , which should open **.htm help** files.

In windows application . i have help provider control. But i could not able to find anything here.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I added a help to my web application too, but in another way. I have a help icon on the top of my master page, which opens a new small window, that shows help belonging to the current site. The user is also able to search for other topics.

Answer (score 0):

the basic is get the key press in java script , match the key then using jquery (my personal perf) open the link of the page. 
and other thing
how are you opening modal dialogs, like using thick box or other java script based plugins or using ajax control toolkit?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want my model dialog just like Excel help window. Excel help window works like , if you navigate from help window to excel cell , help window will not go off. It is still on the page in expanded state. User can parallely look the help window and also work with excel sheet. I need such type of behaviour.